# Not able to insert List<String> into a postgres 9.4 table using hibernate 5.0 where the column to be inserted is of type character varying[]

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, orm

I am using Postgres SQL 9.4.
The database has a table with a column **"food_choices"** of type **character varying[]**
I am using Hibernate 5.0 for ORM purpose
The POJO is like

```
public class Meal implements java.io.Serializable {  
...
    private Serializable foodChoices;

    public Serializable getFoodChoices() {
        return this.foodChoices;
    }

    public void setFoodChoices(Serializable foodChoices) {
        this.foodChoices= foodChoices;
    }

}
```

The hbm for it is like

```
<class name="com.gau.pojo.Meal" table="meal" schema="public">
<property name="foodChoices" type="serializable">
        <column name="food_choices" />
</property>
```

Now I try to insert a record like

```
ArrayList foodChoices=new ArrayList();
foodChoices.add("icecream");
foodChoices.add("fruitnuts";
Meal meals=new Meals();
meals.setFoodChoices(foodChoices.toArray());
```

Now when I try to save this in DB as  `session.save(meals);` ,I get the error as

> ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column  "food_choices" is of type character varying[] but expression is of type bytea
>   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Please help me . I am struck here. Similarly I am unable to fetch the records too. Getting similar error. What is the problem here. I feel i will get similar errors while updating too. What is the correct way to do the CRUD operation?

Comment: You cannot insert Lists in database. You have to create a new table with one-to-many mapping or save all your list contents in one String with comma-seperated values or something like that and push the single string in Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Wrote an custom user type called CharacterVaryingArrayUserType which implements UserType . override the nullSafeGet and nullSafeSet .wrote custom logic inside these two methods, convert the single string and splitted by comma and formed and returned the string array and reverse logic in nullSafeGet